# No instance of function template "max" matches the argument list argument types are (int, int)

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I am just starting with c++ and I don't have a lot of knowledge about templates, I made a template function and I am recieving this error in Visual Studio:

//No instance of function template "max" matches the argument list argument types are (int, int)
//C2664'T max(T &,T &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &'

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
int main()
{
cout << "The Max of 34 and 55 is " << max(34, 55) << endl;
}
```

The copiling error is found in the **max** of the cout

Thank you!

Comment: Drop `using namespace std;` and pass the parameters by value.

Comment: When posting questions regarding build errors, then please copy-paste the actual errors, in full, complete and without modifications into the question body. It should of course include possible informational notes.

Comment: Of course, this code is in a state of sin: `using namespace std;` means that you may well have the standard library's definition of `std::max` in the global namespace as well as your own definition of `max`. That's not what's causing this particular problem, but it **will** bite you eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A non-`const` reference parameter must be backed by an actual variable (loosely speaking). So this would work:

```
template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
int main()
{
int i = 34, j = 55;
cout << "The Max of 34 and 55 is " << max(i, j) << endl;
}
```

However, a `const` reference parameter does not have this requirement. This is probably what you want:

```
template <class T>
T max(const T& t1, const T& t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
int main()
{
cout << "The Max of 34 and 55 is " << max(34, 55) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function is expecting two l-value references, though, what you're passing are two r-values.

Either pass two variables or change the function signature to accept r-value references.

Comment: Or `const` lvalue references.